# aggregation failed when upgrading mongodb version to 3.6

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've recently upgraded MongoDB version from 3.4 to 3.6. I got this error when aggregating : 
The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument ...
any help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101104/mongoerror-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-with-the-expla)

Answer (score 0):

See similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172981/how-to-set-cursor-option-in-aggregate-mongodb)

Changed in version 3.6: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate command without the cursor option unless the command includes the explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must specify the cursor option.